# ASP.NET WebAPI request throttling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I was wondering how request throttling would work with WebApi self-hosting? Would this be something you would have to implement yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to implemented it. The same way you implement it if it was not a self hosted service. Here's a [blog post](http://blog.developers.ba/post/2012/03/03/Request-throttling-in-ASPNET-Web-API.aspx) which illustrates it with an example of a custom delegating handler which achieves this task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that IIS already had a feature which help with request throttling.